# Glitch / bug with table view on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm getting a weird glitch / bug with my UITableView. Everything load up fine, however, when I scroll down to the second cell and back to the first, the label's text in the first cell becomes the same as in the second cell… I'm not really sure why this is happening can you kindly look at my code and help me out.

**Code**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellIdentifier%i",num];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
    }

    UILabel *titleL = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,20)];
    titleL.text = myTitle;

    [cell addSubview:titleL];

    return cell;
}
-(void) makeMeADreamer {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"DreamBits"];
        [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];

        [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            if (!object) {
            } else {
                myTitle = [object objectForKey:@"title"];
                num = i;
                [feed beginUpdates];
                [feed reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:myArr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                [feed endUpdates];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are `alloc/init`ing and `addSubbview`ing a `UILabel` inside your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This means every time this method is called when scrolling more and more labels will be added. Either use Storyboards (and custom cells) or move that code to your `if (cell == nil)` section. Also, what is `myTitle`? Is this a global variable? Have you tried any sort of debugging to check that `myTitle` is being set correctly for the correct index paths?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this code:

```
UILabel *titleL = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,20)];
    titleL.text = myTitle;

    [cell addSubview:titleL];
```

to the `willDisplayCellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Your have the same label text in both cells because your second cell is dequeued from first cell with all its subviews.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString* cellId = @"messagesCell";
     UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
     if (!cell)
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];

     return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UILabel *titleL = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,20)];
    titleL.text = myTitle;

    [cell addSubview:titleL];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't display anything when I use that method

Answer (score 0):

You create the `tableViewCell` in the wrong way. You create a label and add it into the cell each time the table view reload. So you may see many label if you scroll down and up. You should only create one label and re-use it. Try the following code

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
    UILabel *titleL = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,20)];
    titleL.tag = 1234;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:titleL];
}

UILabel *titleL = (UILable*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1234];
titleL.text = myTitle;
```